# How to find Difference between 2 times?

Tags: php, codeigniter, time, controller

Controller Function to insert time:

```
$input = $this->input->post('shiftStartTime');
$input = str_replace(" : ", ":", $input);
$shiftstarttime = date('H:i:s', strtotime($input));

$input2 = $this->input->post('shiftEndTime');
$input2 = str_replace(" : ", ":", $input2);
$shiftEndTime = date('H:i:s', strtotime($input2));
```

I want to take the time difference between 2 times

Here is my code,but it shows wrong difference time.How to solve it?

```
$input3 = $this->input->post('shiftEndTime')-$this->input->post('shiftStartTime');
$input3 = str_replace(" : ", ":", $input3);
$duration = date('H:i:s', strtotime($input3));
```

Comment: use `date_diff()` function

Comment: @ Bilal Ahmed how

Comment: @Saclt7 i have add answer with more details

Comment: what is the format of your dates `shiftStartTime` and `shiftEndTime` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with this `diff` function

```
<?php
$input = $this->input->post('shiftStartTime');
$input = str_replace(" : ", ":", $input);
$shiftstarttime = date('H:i:s', strtotime($input));

$input2 = $this->input->post('shiftEndTime');
$input2 = str_replace(" : ", ":", $input2);
$shiftEndTime = date('H:i:s', strtotime($input2));
echo date_create($shiftEndTime)->diff(date_create($shiftstarttime))->format('%H:%i:%s');
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is multiple way to calculate difference between two times

```
   // example 1
$time1 = "08:00:00";
$time2 = "13:40:00";

echo "Time difference: ".get_time_difference($time1, $time2)." hours<br/>";

// example 2
$time1 = "22:00:00";
$time2 = "04:00:00";

echo "Time difference: ".get_time_difference($time1, $time2)." hours<br/>";

function get_time_difference($time1, $time2)
{
    $time1 = strtotime("1/1/1980 $time1");
    $time2 = strtotime("1/1/1980 $time2");

if ($time2 < $time1)
{
    $time2 = $time2 + 86400;
}

return ($time2 - $time1) / 3600;

}
```

[source code reference](https://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/d/221547-resolved-time-difference-between-two-times)

[Author profile](https://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/u/chris22)

Comment: Here time difference stored in the database as 00:00:00

Comment: `print_r($this->input->post('shiftStartTime'))` print this line and show me result

Comment: Now difference shown.But it is wrong value

Comment: Result is 3 : 14 AM

Answer (score 0):

```
use below code to find the time difference between two times.

$input = $this->input->post('shiftStartTime');
$input = str_replace(" : ", ":", $input); 
$input2 = $this->input->post('shiftEndTime');
$input2 = str_replace(" : ", ":", $input2);   
$date_a = new DateTime($input);
$date_b = new DateTime($input2);
$interval = date_diff($date_a,$date_b);
$diff = $interval->format('%h:%i:%s');
```